# How to update a column in a table from another column in the same table one step back

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-update

Hi I have a table that has a structure like below

| Id | oldid | newid | dateon | currentdate | code |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | NULL | 636 | 2022-03-07 16:02:48.960 | 2022-03-25 10:27:56.393 | 777 |
| 2 | 636 | 202 | 2022-03-25 10:27:56.393 | 2022-05-11 14:34:48.153 | 777 |
| 3 | 202 | 203 | 2022-05-11 14:34:48.153 | 2022-05-12 14:35:42.957 | 777 |
| 4 | 203 | 273 | 2022-05-12 14:35:42.957 | 2022-05-14 14:35:42.957 | 777 |
| 5 | 273 | 189 | 2022-05-14 14:35:42.957 | NULL | 777 |

Currently the column in currentdate is empty. I want to update the column of current date like mentioned above i.e update column currentdate one step back from dateon column.

I tried this query, But it is updating random data

```
UPDATE a 
SET a.currentdate = b.dateon
FROM Table a
LEFT JOIN Table b ON b.code = a.c aodend b.oldid = a.newid
```

Comment: Don't use ascii tables for sample data. Add `CREATE TABLE ...` together with `INSERT INTO ...` statements. You may also use a service like https://dbfiddle.uk/ER_9PaV- to setup youre scenario

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use the lead function within CTE as the following:

```
with cte as
(
  select *,
    lead(dateon) over (partition by code order by dateon) ld
  from table_name
)
update cte set currentdate = ld;
```

[See demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/QP8UHVfI)

Comment: Also, we could use the lag function with the reverse order of dates to get the desired output.